# Building a SPA using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, react-router, redux

I'm building a SPA using reactjs. I know react only provides 'view' part of MVC. So, I'm using React-Router and jquery-ajax with it.

Is it sufficient to build a SPA or do I need something else as well e.g. redux?

Can you also suggest some good react repos to look at to structure my website?

Comment: I would definitely recommend using Redux to manage the global state of your application.

Comment: Would you use redux only or use react-redux?

Comment: Also, is there any other alternative for redux ? Can i manage state using vanila react only?

Comment: Redux is the most popular state management library for React and react-redux is the bindings that help you integrate Redux into your React components. You probably want to use both of them. I wrote [a post on this](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-a-todo-app-using-react-redux-and-immutable-js/) that you might find useful.

Comment: Otherwise, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow as there's no correct answer and it's likely to generate primarily opinion based discussion.

Comment: @DanPrince I know there isn't any correct answer. I'm looking for suggestions only. Thanks for the link. Will go through this.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use `redux`. This means the other dependencies are also included, e.g. `react-redux` and `react-router-redux`.

I would also recommend using `superagent` instead of `jquery-ajax`. It's simpler and also eliminates the needs of jquery.

Comment: How difficult would be state management issue in case i don't use redux?

Comment: and yes, will look into superagent, using axios as of now.

Comment: @AjaySingh it might be a problem when it's getting big. If it's just a small application, feel free to not use Redux.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @kairxa